# GIT: Fatal error when committing HMI project

Tags: git, visual-studio, twincat

After creating an HMI project for my TwinCAT 3 project (TE2000), I'm not able to commit changes to Git.

The error message goes as following:

> Git failed with a fatal error.
> error: open(".engineering_servers/TestLabHMI/TcHmiSrv.lock"): Permission denied
> fatal: Unable to process path .engineering_servers/TestLabHMI/TcHmiSrv.lock

I guess that Git isn't crazy about .lock files or what does this mean? Are there any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if this is a file generated by TwinCAT, you could simply instruct Git to ignore it:

```sh
cd /path/to/repo
echo "*.lock">>.gitignore
git rm --cached .engineering_servers/TestLabHMI/TcHmiSrv.lock
```

Second, that file might be used by another process, preventing Git to read it.

As noted in [Uwe Hafner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505748/uwe-hafner)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68306758/6309), you can actually ignore the parent folder `.engineering_servers/`, which will ignore the lock file anyway.

```sh
cd /path/to/repo
echo ".engineering_servers/">>.gitignore
git rm --cached -r .engineering_servers/
git commit -m "Remove and ignore .engineering_servers/ content"
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes if you have the HMI.sln still open.
Close it and then you can commit the changes.

<s>Unfortunately Beckhoff (the company making twincat) does not have a recommendation yet for HMI projects for gitignore.</s>

**UPDATE**

I got an answer from Beckhoff. If you create a new HMI project with git source control the .gitignore will be put in the folder.
Essentially what you can ignore according to this is the following (gitignore style listing):

```
.engineering_servers/
liveview_*
*.cache
*.db-shm
*.db-wal
*.pid
.hmiframework/
.hmipkgs/*-*-*-*/
tchmipublish.journal.json
```

since the TcHmiSrv.lock is inside .engineering-servers folder it can be ignored.

Comment: Interesting feedback. I would ignore it for now, but I look forward reading your update.

Comment: Got it: no need to ignore the lock file, since the parent folder is ignored.

Comment: @VonC Yes you put it more clearly like that :-)